# Mapping pixel value to temperature value on a thermal image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, heatmap

I have a thermal image (with a color bar) from an IR camera. My goal is to get the temperature of any point by clicking on it.

[image]

I have already written a script that retrieves the RBG values of any pixel by right-clicking on it.

I figure that using the max and min temperatures of the color bar, I can map pixel values to temperature values.

Is this possible or is there a better way to approach this?

Thank you very much.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

counter = 0
max_value = input('Max Temp Value: ')
min_value = input('Min Temp Value: ')

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, params): # Tracks the pixel the mouse it hovering on. When right click it prints the pixel location and its RBG values.                                     
    global counter
    if event == 2:
        counter += 1
        r, g, b = rgb_img.getpixel((x, y))
        print(f'{counter}: {[x, y]} value {r} {g} {b}')
    else:
        print([x, y], end='\t\r', flush=True)

path_image = 'colors.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path_image)
im = Image.open(path_image)
rgb_img = im.convert('RGB')

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

scale_width = width / im.size[0]
scale_height = height / im.size[1]
scale = min(scale_width, scale_height)
window_width = int((im.size[0] * scale) * 0.5)
window_height = int((im.size[1] * scale) * 0.5)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('image', window_width, window_height)

cv2.setMouseCallback('image', mouse_callback)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Sample run]

[image: New approach]

Comment: The colors shown are pseudo-colors. The camera measures a single value per pixel, a color map is used in the display. You should retrieve the original values coming off the sensor, not the colormapped values shown on the display.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @CrisLuengo. How about matching the colors of the pixels(s) in the image and the bar and using its position in the bar to approximate the temperature value? I added a new image to the original question for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to do that. It’s a less precise and more roundabout way of doing it. Simply compare your pixel to each of the pixels along the color bar, and find the closest match (Euclidean distance). That gives you a location along the colorbar that you can directly convert to a value.

Comment: Can we assume that the temperature along the color bar changes linearly(if yes, why?). If that's the case, we can use a linear function relating to colors on the color bar with 2 reference end points and find the temperature corresponding to any color